# Yammer - How to Post Video to Yammer using Open Graph or REST API

Tags: yammer

I want to post a video to Yammer which can be played in Newsfeed itself.

It is possible?

Comment: The REST API is documented at https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/ and includes information about attaching files. The same would be true for any kind of attachment, video or not. The second half of your question is unclear. What do you mean by "Played in the newsfeed itself"?

Comment: "Played in the newsfeed itself" means that, from the newsfeed, you would be able to press a play button and watch the video. You get this behavior when uploading attachments through Yammer, but (so far) uploading attachments via the Yammer API doesn't seem to have the same behavior for me.